# Why is a man apparently referred to as feminine when translating "You followed him?" as "¿La seguiste tú?"

Tags: traducción, género

This passage from Tom Sawyer:

> —You followed him?
>
> —¿La seguiste tú?

... seems to indicate that Indian Joe is a woman, because it uses "La" - right? I don't know Spanish that well, so I could be wrong (probably am); but why would "La" be used here and, if this translation *is* wrong, what should it be instead.

For some context on the passage, here it is with the precieding sentence prepended:

> —Oh yes! Why, it seems 'bout a year ago. It was that very night that I follered Injun Joe to the widder's.
>
> —You followed him?

Which is translated as:

> —¡Es verdad! Parece que ya hace años de eso. Fue la noche en que fui siguiendo a Joe el Indio hasta la casa de la viuda.
>
> —¿La seguiste tú?

Comment: that translation seems to suffer from a lot of mistranslations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in *¿La seguiste tú?*, the pronoun *la* refers undoubtedly to someone (or something) of the feminine grammatical gender. In this case, the text is about following a person, so it should be a woman. It must be a mistake, either a translation mistake or a typo (*la* instead of *lo*).